# How to use directshow filter as a live input for Expression Encoder 4?

Tags: directshow, expression-encoder

I have a directshow filter that reads M2TS stream and demux it. I can render video and audio in GraphStudio and see it.
My question is how can I use this filter as a live source for Expression Encoder job?
I saw some recommendations saying to use subgraphs, but I am not so familiar with DirectShow to understand what it is.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression Encoder would look for DirectShow video source devices, which are typically cameras. You might want to implement your won virtual camera so that `EE4` would pick it up and start receiving video from it.

A popular sample on doing it is Vivek's virtual camera project available from http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm (4th link).

Comment: Virtual Cam (and PushSource) seem to segfault Expression Encoder when selected as source, as an FYI.