# Custom virtual video capture device

Tags: directshow, expression-encoder, ms-media-foundation

I`m new to media foundation and C++.
But I want to create a virtual video capture device which can be used by Microsoft Expression Encoder.
Can you tell me in which direction to look?
I think it should be something working asynchronously and a source will be byte stream from mobile device.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to look into Media Foundation for this. Expression Encoder uses a richer API to capture video with, `DirectShow`. You want a virtual DirectShow camera, which was discussed multiple times and has a simple sample project to start from.

- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)
- [Simulate a DirectShow Webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996194/simulate-a-directshow-webcam)
- [How to use directshow filter as a live input for Expression Encoder 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870843/how-to-use-directshow-filter-as-a-live-input-for-expression-encoder-4)

[Supported USB Capture Devices Expression Encoder 4](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/is/encoder/thread/c00d4ce2-6928-481b-aca7-1321e01437df):

> Any device that provides a dshow filter is supported by EE4.
>   Currently, there is no list currently available of supported devices,
>   though most usb devices have little to no issues with encoder.