# Where can I find out about the Windows video capture architecture, and specifically virtual webcam drivers?

Tags: windows, driver, virtual, device

I saw a Lenovo platform with Win7 that has a web cam and and a virtual web cam. The virtual web cam renders the video that is captured by the physical web cam but supports image processing. It also works in parallel to the physical web cam (one application is using the web cam and another application uses the virtual web cam).

Where can I find documentation on the windows architecture, to program such virtual camera and feed it from the physical device?

Thanks,
Shai

Answer (score 1):

The primary API for video capture in Windows is [still] [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). A question of implementing a virtual video capture device has been discussed multiple times here on SO and on MSDN Forums:

- [Custom virtual video capture device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569238/custom-virtual-video-capture-device?lq=1)
- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream) and the links there

In the virtual camera you are free to choose where you take video feed from, would it be real capture device or the feed is generated, or taken from network etc.